# delphi / firemonkey: how to make a kinetic scroll?

Tags: delphi, mobile, scroll, firemonkey, gesture

I m under delphi and firemonkey. i manage myself the scroll via the ongesture event. i would like to add something like a "kinetic energy" effect to the scroll.

for exemple you put your finger on the bottom of the screen and you fastly move it to the top and removing it from the screen. the result will be that the screen will scroll much much more than where you remove your finger, like you gave some kinetic energy to the scroll. on the other way if you don't remove you finger from the screen at the end then you don't give any kinetic energy to the scroll.

any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TVertScrollBox` for making kinetic energy on your screen. It will help you.

Comment: but the TVertScrollBox have a very slow kinetic energy :( i want something more strong, and it's can not be configured in TVertScrollBox :(

Comment: If you have pre-defined items or dynamic list for anything, you can use TListBox. It has really cool kinetic energy and also you can add your items. If you want, I can send you example.